# How to write query using LIKE to accept special characters also?

Tags: php, mysql, sql-like

Am having one value in database as "123-456-789". My query is

> SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE phone LIKE "%123456789%"

But it is not giving the result. Any idea

Comment: You can use regex

Comment: @SougataBose Maybe you want to lead him to further information on RegEx, since RegEx is kind of advanced stuff. Consider your suggestions as a full written answer. I'd appreciate it, too.

Comment: Is 123456789 the specific mumber you are after? or are you looking to just search for any number  '%[^0-9.]%'

Comment: The number is not specific. It will get change. Sometimes we will check with dashes or without dashes. If those numbers are there, result should get display. Is it possible? @ColinGell

Comment: Use '%[0-9]%'     instead of '%123456789%'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course ,you excluded the dashes so it does not match the middle part. The logic of your query is "anything before my string and anything after" but the middle part should be the same.

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE phone LIKE "%123-456-789%"
```

This will work.

But if you want to exclude dashes you can do something like:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE REPLACE(phone ,'-','') = "123456789"
```

If your input includes also dashes then you can remove them as well:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE REPLACE(phone ,'-','') = REPLACE('123456789','-','')
```

That way you can search a number with dashes or without but dashes will never be taken under consideration.

Comment: Sometimes i will check with those dashes also. If am checking with dash or not, the result should come if those numbers are there @pr1nc3

Comment: Edited my answer

Comment: Done. Working fine

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE `phone` LIKE '%[0-9]' '_' '[0-9]' '_' [0-9]%'
```

You might also consider some OR statements

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE `phone` LIKE '%[0-9]' '_' '[0-9]' '_' [0-9]%' OR '%[0-9]%'
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a `regex` directly within mySQL like this:

```
select * from `table_name` where `phone` regexp '[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}';
```